# The top and bottom of the app are hidden by Android’s top and bottom bars in android 13

Tags: android, cordova

**Problem**
In Android 13, our app does not display correctly. The top and bottom of the screen are obscured by the phone’s status strip at the top, and control strip at the bottom.

**What is expected to happen?**
UI should have been rendered inside webview, that is, screen area which excludes system top bar and bottom bar

**What does actually happen?**
UI gets rendered in full screen which includes systems top bar and bottom bars as well. Hence, systems ui getting displayed but mobile apps top/bottom bars and not getting displayed.

**Information**
**Device Details:**
1)Samsung Galaxy A32 5G
Android 13
Samsung One UI 5.0
2)Samsung SM-A326W
Android 13

**Images**
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=14F48D183050714E%21397921&authkey=%21AMvEMqR7WyJviYM&ithint=photo%2cjpg&e=rfsg1m

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=14F48D183050714E%21397922&authkey=%21APVUnXAtxuBxINc&ithint=photo%2cjpg&e=C8UJWx

**Note:**
We are using voltbuilder to create andorid app, config file used to pass cordova details to voltbuilder as follows:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=14F48D183050714E%21397920&authkey=%21AGU9mKQgna2yhek&e=kwW8IB

Comment: What's your viewport meta in your index.html ?

Comment: @Eric <meta name="viewport" content=" viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />

Comment: Try with this setting `StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);` add to `config.xml`

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and I fixed it by uninstalling the `cordova-plugin-statusbar` plugin and it was solved. I am using the capacitor plugin.